# Bitbucket - Git submodule update asking for user and password

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-submodules

I have two projects within the same bitbucket user, one of them is a submodule of the first one.

When I have changes in main project *git fetch origin* and *git merge origin/master* work fine, but as soon as I have any change at the submodule *git fetch origin* ask me for my user and password at bitbucket.

Why is that? both project have configured the deployment key at the bitbucket settings

Comment: are you using https links, or git@bitbucket.org:username/repo-path type connections? I'm struggling with this myself, but basically you will need to set up an ssh deployment key on your server and set that in your bitbucket account. Private submodules also need their own keys to, but separately aliased. Which is where things get crazy. https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Add+an+SSH+key+to+an+account